# What is a nice way to override the value a promise resolves to?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise

I am writing a Node.js script to populate an SQL database with a test dataset.

In the promise chain illustrated in the code snippet below (the real code is a bit more hairy), the function `insertData()` requires the `db` object to be passed through from the previous stage. However, asynchronous calls inside `dropAndCreateTables()` on the previous stage use `db` object but do not return it. I came up with a solution that wraps promises inside `dropAndCreateTables()` into another promise object that resolves to a `db` object. However:

- I heard that using `Promise()` constructor in non-library code is an antipattern and may lead to subtle and hard-to-diagnose mistakes
- I heard that nesting `then()`-chains is also an antipattern
- It does not allow me to ignore errors from the `promiseDrop` (for example, I don't care if tables don't exist on drop)
- It is ugly

**Questions:**

- Is there a simpler, nicer and more socially accepted way to override the return value of a promise? (in this case, created with `Promise.all()`)
- Is there a way to restructure my code in a way that this problem does not occur? (That is, I don't exclude the possibility of "XY problem" here)

**Code:**

```
const dropAndCreateTables = (db, startClean) => {
  if(startClean) {
    const sqlDrop = fs.readFileSync('drop.sql').toString()
    const promiseDrop = db.raw(sqlDrop)

    const sqlCreate = fs.readFileSync('create.sql').toString()
    const promiseCreate = db.raw(sqlCreate)

    /********* Problems here? ************************************/
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {      // Ew?
      Promise.all([promiseDrop, promiseCreate])
        .then(() => {
          resolve(db) // Override the returned value
        })
        .catch(reject)
    })

  }
  return Promise.resolve(db)
}

initDB({ debug: false })
  .then((db) => {
    return dropAndCreateTables(db, START_CLEAN) // Without my hack this does not return `db`
  })
  .then((db) => {
    return insertData(db, DO_UPSERT)  // This needs the `db` object
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.info(`\n${timestamp()} done`)
  })
  .catch(handleError)
```

Comment: Indeed, a duplicate. How could I miss that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Some fairly important notes midway and later in the answer, please do read all the way to the end.)*

> Is there a simpler, nicer and more socially accepted way to override the return value of a promise? (in this case, created with `Promise.all()`)

Yes, you simply return a value from the `then` handler, and return the promise `then` returns:

```
return Promise.all([promiseDrop, promiseCreate])
    .then(() => db);
```

`then` (and `catch`) create promise *chains*. Each link in the chain can transform the result. `then` and `catch` return a new promise that will be fulfilled or rejected based on what happens in their callback:

- If their callback throws, the promise rejects with the error thrown
- If their callback returns a non-thenable value (e.g., promise), the promise is fulfilled with that value
- If their callback returns a thenable value, the promise is *resolved to* that thenable — it waits for the other promise to settle, then settles the same way

*(If the term "thenable" isn't familiar, or you're not clear on the distinction between "fulfill" and "resolve," I go into promise terminology in [this post](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/) on my blog.)*

> I heard that using `Promise()` constructor in non-library code is an antipattern and may lead to subtle and hard-to-diagnose mistakes

The distinction isn't library code vs. non-library code, it's between code that doesn't already have a promise to work with and code that does. If you already have a promise to work with, you almost never want to use `new Promise`. More: [*What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

> I heard that nesting then()-chains is also an antipattern

You almost never need to *nest* `then` chains, because again each link in the chain already has the means of tranforming the result passing through it. So:

```
// Unnecessary nesting
doSomething()
    .then(a => {
        return doSomethingElse(a * 2)
            .then(b => b * 3);
    })
    .catch(e => { /*...handle error...*/ });
```

can be more idiomatically and simply written:

```
doSomething()
    .then(a => doSomethingElse(a * 2))
    .then(b => b * 3);
    .catch(e => { /*...handle error...*/ });
```

> Is there a way to restructure my code in a way that this problem does not occur? (That is, I don't exclude the possibility of "XY problem" here)

Not an X/Y per se, but you have a problem in that code: There's no guarantee the `drop` will happen before the `create`! So instead of starting both and letting them run in parallel and watching for the results with `Promise.all`, ensure those operations happen *in sequence*:

```
// Fairly minimal changes
const dropAndCreateTables = (db, startClean) => {
  if(startClean) {
    const sqlDrop = fs.readFileSync('drop.sql').toString()
    return db.raw(sqlDrop)
      .then(() => {
        const sqlCreate = fs.readFileSync('create.sql').toString()
        return db.raw(sqlCreate);
      })
      .then(() => db);
  }
  return Promise.resolve(db)
}
```

**But**, I wouldn't use sync file I/O. Instead

```
const promisify = require("utils").promisify;
const readWithPromise = promisify(fs.readFile);
```

and then

```
const dropAndCreateTables = (db, startClean) => {
  if(startClean) {
    const getDrop = readWithPromise('drop.sql');       // Start this first
    const getCreate = readWithPromise('create.sql');   // Then start this
    return getDrop
      .then(dropSql => db.raw(dropSql))                // Got the drop SQL, run it
      .then(() => getCreate)                           // Make sure we have the create SQl
      .then(createSql => db.raw(createSql))            // Run it
      .then(() => db);
  }
  return Promise.resolve(db)
}
```

Note how we avoid ever busy-waiting on I/O, and we can overlap the DB's drop operation with reading the create SQL.

Comment: `You almost never need to nest then chains` -> IMO this is one of the rare usecases

Comment: Thank you, I learned a lot from your answer! About nested chains: we both came up with `dropAndCreateTables()` that has a chain inside it, which is nested inside the main chain in the global scope. Isn't resulting `dropAndCreateTables()` is similar to the `a => {}` function in your "Unnecessary nesting" example? We cannot refactor the chain out of the `dropAndCreateTables()`. Hence, my confusion with chain nesting guidelines. Could you comment on that?

Comment: @Drop: You mean the "Minimal changes" code? No, that's not *promise* nesting. That's promise chaining. It's fine (and common) to *initiate* a promise in a `then` handler if you have to, which is what that code does.

Comment: @JonasW.: Why? I don't see any benefit to it here at all.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No, I meant another thing. If I replace the call to `dropAndCreateTables()` by the contents of it (any version), wouldn't it become the same pattern as illustrated by `return doSomethingElse(a * 2).then(b => b * 3);` in the "Unnecessary nesting" example? I fact I tried to do eliminate the call and then to eliminate nesting, but I was uncertain what to do with that `if` statement. Or is it not the kind of nesting I should eliminate? (I have tons more of this kind of nesting in other, more complicated functions)

Comment: @Drop: I'm sorry, I don't follow what you mean there.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry for not making myself clear. Another attempt: if we replace the call to function `dropAndCreateTables()` with that functions' body (for example, [like this](https://pastebin.com/7QnExhmR)), will resulting nested structure become similar to the  example marked by a comment "Unnecessary nesting" in your answer?

Comment: @Drop: Don't assume the problem was at your end. ;-D Yes, it looks similar, but the reason for that is you have two distinct branches in there thanks to the `if (startClearn)`, so you have to have two chains, not just one. That's one of the few times you might need nesting. Although at that point, you should do exactly what you've done: extract the logic in to a smaller piece -- `dropAndCreateTables` -- that you can call. Smaller pieces are easier to comprehend, and easier to combine. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you so much, especially for mentioning `promisify`. It just has changed my life completely. =)

Comment: @Drop: LOL Also check out this npm module: [promisify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify). Instead of working at the individual function level, it works at the full API level.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call the `Promise` constructor when returning another promise, you can just write it like:

```
return Promise.all([promiseDrop, promiseCreate])
    .then(() => db)
    .catch(error => {
       // handle the error or rethrow it
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You might omit resolving `db` from `dropAndCreateTables` like this:

```
.then((db) => {
    return dropAndCreateTables(db, START_CLEAN).then(Promise.resolve(db));
})
```

Comment: I actually like this solution. However, would it properly handle errors, in particular for `promiseCreate`?

Answer (score 1):

You should not let dropAndCreateTables return a db promise, there is no real usecase for it. So:

```
return Promise.all([promiseDrop, promiseCreate]);
```

is enough. Now the chaining part:

```
initDB({ debug: false }).then(async (db) => {

  await dropAndCreateTables(db, START_CLEAN);
  await insertData(db, DO_UPSERT);

  console.info(`\n${timestamp()} done`)
}).catch(handleError)
```

Comment: Yes, with `async/await` it is indeed much nicer. I tried this yesterday and converted the entire script to use `async/await`. After I added error checking `try/catch` clauses my script has become absolutely unreadable, so I rolled back to `then()/catch()`. However, converting this particular part might be actually worthwhile. I am currently investigating whether I should wrap EVERY async call into `try/catch` or whether they can be grouped. In the latter case I often get unhanded rejection warnings.

Comment: @drop you just need to catch them once. So you actually only need 1 catch at the highest level. But that depends on your code strucure.